# Update Values in R values greater than 0 to 1 in numeric columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 1:13 character columns and 14:176 numeric columns. i want to replace all values greater than 0 from 1 in numeric columns only.

i tried with:

```
HRtest1 <- cbind(HRtest[,1:13], 
                 apply(HRtest[,14:176], 2, function(x) {replace(x, x>0, 1)}))
```

but this code is working only when i change my data frame to matrix and some of values are not updating(like 184.97965 is still there).

another code i tried with is:

```
HRtest1<- as.data.table(lapply(HRtest, function(x){replace(x, x >0,1)}))
```

but with this character columns also update to 1. please help me with this.

Comment: Please check the `str(HRtest)`

Comment: > class(HRtest)
[1] "data.table" "data.frame" 
checked str(HRtest) and found only two columns in number rest all are character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways to deal with this. But I would like a general scenario. The reason why the strings/characters are changing is because they are taken to be factors. Please ensure you change the class to characters :

```
 A[,1:13]=sapply(A[,1:13],as.character)
 sapply(A, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) replace(x,x>0,1) else x)
```

or you can just decide and go ahead and do:

```
A[,-(1:13)]=sapply(A[,-(1:13)],function(x) replace(x,x>0,1))
```

Comment: some columns in range column[14:176] is in character and not changing to numeric i tried with.
 A[,14:176]=sapply(A[,14:176],as.numeric) but some columns numbers are updating from column 14 to 176.
sapply(A, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) replace(x,x>0,1) else x) is working fine for so now if we change data type successfully then we done.

Comment: I see. well, your initial question clearly stated that **ALL** the columns after 13 are numeric. That is why I gave an extra code. Please be more specific when asking the question. Anyway I am glad the code did work after you twisted it.. That's great. Hope you changed all the factors into numeric. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
HRtest[,14:176][HRtest[,14:176] > 0] <- 1
```

should work.

You basically take column 14 to 176, create a `TRUE` and `FALSE` Matrix in the same dimensions, and set all `TRUE` values to `1`.

Comment: still there is one column which is.numeric(HRtest$F1136) = True but some values are not updating to 1 while it is numeric column.

Comment: So in this case, I guess we need some sample data... Or what is the output of `grep('F1136', names(HRtest))`?

Comment: it is 14 and data is

F1136
-1017.38809
-305.21643
-739.91861
184.97965
1849.79652
-18497.96523
462.44913
175.73067
24.04735
434.48021
178.76434
1942.28635
4855.71587
971.14317
2913.42952
236.77395
97.11432
610.43285
101.73881
870.32926
1435.44212
661.30227
305.21641
3.17148
31.71476

Comment: I would suggest to add the output of `dput(HRtest[,13:15])` to your question to make kind of minimal example what your tried!

Comment: some columns in range [14:176] is in character and not changing to numeric i tried with. A[,14:176]=sapply(A[,14:176],as.numeric) but some columns numbers are updating from column 14 to 176 instead of values.

sapply(A, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) replace(x,x>0,1) else x) is working fine for so now if we change data type for [14:176] successfully then we done. HRtest is Data table

Comment: So sorry, but with no example data and reproducible example, the might be no real help!

Comment: for(i in 13:176)
  {
    HRtest[[i]] <- as.numeric(HRtest[[i]])
  } 

resolved the issue, there was data formatting issue. many thanks for your support